# Laragon 4.0.15 - Apache fails to start after switching to PHP 8

Tags: php, apache, laragon, php-8

On Windows 10 Pro, after downloading PHP 8, switching to it in Laragon (PHP > Version) and restarting Apache, I get the following error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 546 of
C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15/con...:
Syntax error on line 2 of
C:/laragon/etc/apache2/mod_php.conf: Can't locate
API module structure 'php8_module' in file
C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.2-Win32-vs16-x64/php8a...:
No error
```

Comment: Useful link https://dev.to/dendihandian/php-8-on-laragon-e8j

Answer (score 13):

After a fair bit of head scratching, the fix was fairly simple - in file

`C:/laragon/etc/apache2/mod_php.conf`

I changed

`LoadModule php8_module` to `LoadModule php_module`

It seems Laragon fouls up the auto-configuration of PHP 8

Comment: Dude after hours you saved my head from getting smashed to the wall

Comment: Looks like we need to make this change every time we switch the php version. Any hint on how to change the auto-generated `mod_php.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

**GOTO**

C:/laragon/etc/apache2/mod_php.conf

## AND REPLACE THIS

```
#This file is auto-generated, so please keep it intact.
LoadModule php8_module "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64"
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

## WITH THIS

```
#This file is auto-generated, so please keep it intact.
LoadModule php_module "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64"
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```